# Can't make moving container gradually bigger and from the screen center smaller in flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, containers

I have been trying to make a container that transitions from left to right, increasing in size until it reaches the center, after reaching center it decreases in size.
I have tried to use two controllers and more Tween-s but didn't find a result.

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';

class Basic_animation_view extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Basic_animation_viewState createState() => _Basic_animation_viewState();
}

class _Basic_animation_viewState extends State<Basic_animation_view>
  with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Offset> animation;
  Animation<Size> growAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 3))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
    animation = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, 0), end: Offset(5, 0))
        .animate(controller);

    growAnimation =
        Tween<Size>(begin: Size(50.0, 50.0), end: Size(100.0, 100.0))
            .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: controller,curve: Curves.linear));

    controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SlideTransition(
              position: animation,
              child: Container(***strong text***
                width:growAnimation.value.width,
                height:growAnimation.value.height,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe an animated container class will be closer to what you want. You
>   can find more details using the documented sample with more details
>   found at the [source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html).

```
// Flutter code sample for

// The following example (depicted above) transitions an AnimatedContainer
// between two states. It adjusts the [height], [width], [color], and
// [alignment] properties when tapped.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selected = !selected;
        });
      },
      child: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          width: selected ? 200.0 : 100.0,
          height: selected ? 100.0 : 200.0,
          color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
          alignment:
              selected ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: FlutterLogo(size: 75),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer but my main problem is to have the container that should move from left to right continuously and at the same time change size gradually to become bigger at the center of the screen and from the center should decrease the size until the end of the screen.

Comment: use the Positioned widget.

Comment: @RobertKovačić - Try wrapping the Center in the AnimatedPositioned widget. Test for effect. See how-two (https://youtu.be/hC3s2YdtWt8)